# Every month there is prize draw, whats the probability of winning prize draw of 20 customers

Tags: probability

> Every month there is a prize draw for customers who complete the
>   survey. One customer will win the prize. Last month 20 customers
>   completed the survey.  what chance does the customer, Bradley have of
>   winning the prize for last month's?

**My attempt**:

My answer is $5$, because calculating weeks by $20$ customers, one month there are $4$ weeks and divide that by $20$ customers.

Comment: Did you actually try to solve this?

Comment: yes, my answer is 5.

Comment: How did you find the answer?

Comment: calculating weeks by 20 customers, one month there are 4 weeks and divide that by 20 customers.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that we can see what you did?

Comment: I am very new to this web, so I did,   20/4=5

Comment: OK I'll edit the question for you.

Comment: You got an answer of $5$ for a probability question?  You are aware of the fact that probabilities are **always** numbers between $0$ and $1$, right?  Like... something could have a $0.5$ (also sometimes said aloud as "50 percent") chance of happening such as the probability of flipping a fair coin and it landing on heads...

Comment: The calculation you did of $20$ customers and $4$ weeks (*most months have 30 or 31 days, not 28 days so 4 weeks per month is not quite correct*) would have given "How many customers completed the survey per week on average for this month."  This is irrelevant to the question of calculating the probability of winning the prize.

Comment: The calculation you have done made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is one draw per month, and Bradly participated in the draw for a single month for which there were $20$ participants in total, the probability that Bradley wins is

$$
1/20.
$$

Comment: I have calculated and yes my answer is 1/20,  appreciated.

Comment: @NaveenBashir If you like my answer don't forget to upvote/accept it, thank you :)

Comment: I am trying to see how to upvote/accept it. This site is too complicated for a person like me:) I will do it.

Comment: @NaveenBashir Next to the number on the left hand side of this post there is an up arrow. And also a "tick" mark that you can click :)